# Storing users sessions

Tags: php

I have a login and signup page, actually i want to store users sessions when they click logout button,they are not allowed to enter the home page until they enter their user name and password..!
On the login page i have the code for storing the session.

```
 $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];
```

And on the home page i have the condition..

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user_name']==1){
    header("location:login.php?error=You must be logged in first!");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The main issue is that when user clicks logout and redirects to the login page ..if he type the home page URL in the addressbar..he reaches the home page without entering the passsword and login..What's the problem..

Comment: **Note:** Don't rely on the query string (`?error=xxx`) to be 100% safe when you're blinding `echo` it out. Someone could put some XSS in there...

Comment: Also the header is wrong formatted. The Location has to be an absolute URL. It's neither absolute (no http:// there) nor a URL (here ae spaces! use urlencode() or similar!) In practice all relevant clients support relative URLs there but the encoding should be correct ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Log in on submit
    if (isset($_POST['user_name']) /* whatever */) {
        // Do some login validations here
        // and if successful, set the session then redirect
        $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $_POST['user_name'];
        header('Location: /members.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Unset all session values 
    $_SESSION = array();

    // get session parameters 
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    // Delete the actual cookie. 
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);

    // Destroy the session 
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: /login.php");
?>
```

members.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Check if authenticated
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
        header("location:login.php?error=You must be logged in first!");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: @ keziah ! Could you please tell me why you used the local variable "$ssession" in: $session->destroy();

Comment: sorry, that should be `session_destroy()` because I'm using session class